# Условие внутри массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте!
Прошу Вас помочь разобраться в достаточно простой (на мой взгляд) задаче.
Необходимо применить условие внутри массива.
Имеем следующее:

```
<?php
$test = array(
    'TYPE' => $getType;
);
?>
```

В данном массиве необходимо выполнить условие аналогичное этому:

```
<?php
if($getType == 'Type1') {
    $getType = 'Y';
} else {
    $getType = 'N';
};
?>
```

"Гуглил" в сторону этого: array $a == $b ? 'a' : 'b'; но что-то понять мне ничего совсем не удалось.

Грубо говоря, я хочу получить что-то вроде этого:

```
<?php
$test = array(
    'TYPE' => if($getType == 'Type1') { $getType = 'Y'; } else { $getType = 'N'; }
);
?>
```

Comment: `'TYPE' => (($getType == 'Type1') ? 'Y' : 'N')`

Comment: @cyadvert, спасибо большое, вопрос решен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать тернарный оператор

```
$test = array(
     'TYPE' => ($getType == 'Type1' ? $getType = 'Y' : $getType = 'N')
);
```